# Why does the following integral generate an error message for Delete::partw and Integrate`ImproperDump`tmp

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following integral generates a couple of errors that I'm not sure what they mean or how to prevent them

```
Integrate[
Log[Sqrt[(0.27059805007309845` - 
  0.7071067811865475` s)^2 + (-0.2705980500730985` + 
  0.7071067811865475` s)^2]], {s, .3826, .3829}]
```

errors

> Delete::partw: Part 2 of Integrate`ImproperDump`tmp does not exist. >>
>
> Join::heads: Heads List and Delete at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same. >>

Comment: I got `-0.00291087 + 0.601118 i` with M10.

Comment: 1) The numerical `NIntegrate` is typically more appropriate than the symbolic integrator `Integrate` if you want a numerical approximation of an integral. Symbolic and numerical integration use VERY different approaches. Those errors are probably cause by `Integrate`'s internal routines getting tripped up by your machine-precision input. 2) Your integrand has a singularity within the integration domain that is probably going to cause trouble.

Comment: @happyfish For $s = 0.382683$ the argument of the logarithm vanishes, so you are trying to calculate $\log0$. I am not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: @MarcoB sorry I ignored the negative sign before 0.27. but `Minimize` is not giving the correct result anyway maybe due to precision errors.

Comment: @happyfish Try ``NMinimize[(0.27059805007309845 -      0.7071067811865475` s)^2 + (-0.2705980500730985` +      0.7071067811865475` s)^2, s]``, which returns `{3.08149*10^-33, {s -> 0.382683}}`. The value at minimum is close enough to zero when allowances are made for numerical inaccuracy. You can also try `Solve[argumentOfSqrt == 0, s]`, which will return a comparable result.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks. I am not familiar with numerical calculations.

Comment: The messages comprise a small bug. Will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I think NIntegrate is what I was looking for. By using some of it's options the errors disappear since I can identify the singularity and integrate around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Integrate[
Log[Abs[2 (0.27059805007309845` - 
  0.7071067811865475` s)]], {s, .3826, .3829}]
(*-0.00280689*)
```

returns no errors, since it is the same with your integral.