# Integration giving unknown messages

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate the following

```
Integrate[(Log[1 - t] t^(-(1/2) + eps))/(1 + t),{t,0,1}]
```

To simplify this I am doing a further transformation `t->r^2`:

```
Integrate[(2 r^(2 eps) Log[1-r^2])/(1+r^2),{r,0,1},GenerateConditions->True,Assumptions->{eps>0}] //Timing
{88.6184,  ConditionalExpression[  1/2 (HarmonicNumber[-(1/2) + eps]^2 - HarmonicNumber[eps]^2 - PolyGamma[1, 1/2 + eps] + PolyGamma[1, 1 + eps]), Re[Integrate`ImproperDump`epsilon$1241384] > 0 && Im[Integrate`ImproperDump`epsilon$1241384] == 0]}

Collect[Normal[Series[%, {eps, 0, 3}]], eps] // N
{88.6184, -0.684028 + 0.371253 eps - 0.240723 eps^2 + 0.163299 eps^3}
```

I did not understand the conditions it has generated.

If I do the expansion first (might be questionable due to `r->1` limit?) I get a different result,

```
CoefficientList[ Normal[Series[(2 r^(2 eps) Log[1 - r^2])/(1 + r^2), {eps, 0, 3}]], eps];
NIntegrate[%, {r, 0, 1}]
{-0.743138, 0.426997, -0.281255, 0.189561}
```

My question is which procedure is wrong? I believe the second one due to `r->1` might not be defined. But then I did not understand the condition message generated in the analytic approach:

```
 Re[Integrate`ImproperDump`epsilon$1241384] > 0 && Im[Integrate`ImproperDump`epsilon$1241384] == 0
```

`$Version` : "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"

---

EDIT:

I found another [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113748/why-does-the-following-integral-generate-an-error-message-for-deletepartw-and) that suggests using `Abs` inside the `Log` but does not change anything for `Integrate`.

---

EDIT-2: Just to add some more observations:

It seems the `Integrate` in this case is not giving the correct result.

```
j=CoefficientList[ Normal[Series[(2 r^(2 eps) Log[1 - r^2])/(1 + r^2), {eps, 0, 3}]], eps]
```

> {(2 Log[1 - r^2])/(1 + r^2),
> (4 Log[r] Log[1 - r^2])/(1 + r^2),
> (4 Log[r]^2 Log[1 - r^2])/(1 + r^2),
> (8 Log[r]^3 Log[1 - r^2])/(3 (1 + r^2))}

```
NIntegrate[j, {r, 0, 1}]//Timing
```

> {0.104228, {-0.743138, 0.426997, -0.281255, 0.189561}}

```
Integrate[j,{r,0,1},GenerateConditions->False]//Timing
```

> {340.878,
> {-2 Catalan + 1/2 [Pi] Log[2],
> 1/48 (15 [Pi]^3 - 384 Catalan Log[2] + 10 I [Pi]^2 Log[2] + 12 [Pi] Log[2]^2 - 2 I (4 Log[2]^3 - 192 PolyLog[3, 1/2 + I/2] + 105 Zeta[3])),
> -((11 [Pi]^4)/90) + 7 Log[4] Zeta[3],
> -(1/3) [Pi]^4 Log[2] - 10/3 [Pi]^2 Zeta[3] + 60 Zeta[5]}}

```
%//N
```

> {340.878, {-0.743138, 0.426997, -0.240723, 0.163299}}

It thus follows that in the integrands associated with `eps^2, eps^3`
there is something strange.

Attempting the same with the original integrand in `t` kills the kernel.

*Checked with 13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)*

Comment: **Assumtions->{eps>0}** I assume you used `Assumptions` in your actual code and not `Assumtions`?  Besides this, on V 13.3.1 it does not evaluate: ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ohV.png)

Comment: @Nasser    I have used the correct one during the evaluation. It is just a mistake while writing here. I have corrected that now.

Comment: Since you are using V 12, which is 4 years old, this looks like a bug that was since fixed since the integral does not evaluate now.  These messages `Integrate``ImproperDump``epsilon$1241384` are clearly leaked symbols from internal code and should not show up.

Comment: @Nasser         I have tried it with V13.1.0 and the problem is still there. Maybe it was fixed later as you said.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, your aim is to find the integral depending on `eps`.
The result of

```
Series[Log[1 - t] t^(-1/2 + eps)/(1 + t), {t, 0, 3}] // Normal
```

> `t^eps (-Sqrt[t] + t^(3/2)/2 - (5 t^(5/2))/6)`

implies its convergence iff `eps>-3/2`. Knowing it, we need not in `GenerateConditions` at all

```
j = Integrate[Log[1 - t] t^(-1/2 + eps)/(1 + t), {t, 0, 1}, 
Assumptions -> eps > -3/2, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> `(-4*HarmonicNumber[1/2 + eps] - 2*Gamma[3/2 + eps]* (Derivative[{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1}, 0][HypergeometricPFQRegularized][ {1, 2, 2}, {5/2 + eps, 2}, 1/2] -  2*(Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][Hypergeometric2F1Regularized][1, 1/2 + eps,  5/2 + eps, -1] + Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][ Hypergeometric2F1Regularized][1, 1/2 + eps, 5/2 + eps, -1])))/ (4 + 8*eps)`

We should  test the behavior of the analytic expression `j` at `eps==-1/2` because of the denominator `4+8*eps`.

```
j /. eps -> -0.499
```

> `-1.06174`

Last, but not least: numerical test of `j`

```
NIntegrate[Log[1 - t] t^(-1/2 + eps)/(1 + t) /. eps -> -0.499, {t, 0, 1}]
```

> `-1.06174`

All that is done in 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

Edit. `Series`.

Comment: All I want is the eps expasion of the correct result. Unfortunately, I do not have access to 13.3.1. But with 12 I could reproduce your result although it generates a lot of messages like `RecursionLimit, IterationLimit exceeded, Hold[Select::normal :  Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Select[Integrate`TableDump`res$39229,Last[#1]=!={}&].]`.  
If I try to get the leading term setting eps->0 limit, I get `0.25 (-2.45482 - 
   1.77245 (-0.933543 - 
      2. (True Return[-0.418354] + True Return[-0.194467])))`. 
I believe the `NIntegrate` is giving correct result even in V12.

Comment: @BabaYaga: You wrote "I have tried it with V13.1.0 and the problem is still there. Maybe it was fixed later as you said" . Try it in free Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: Yes. In all mathematica versions up to 13.1.0, the `NIntegrate` (first expanding the integrand in `eps` and then performing `NIntegration`) gives the same result & is quoted in the question. Now the problem is the `Integrate` which gives some results but it seems different from `NIntegrate`.  I tried your method in V13.1.0 and could generate the result and also the correct leading term (eps=0) which is the same as the `NIntegrate`. Even with `HypExp` I could also exactly get the `NIntegrate` results. Unfortunately, I could not get the analytical `eps` - expanded results by any of the methods.

Comment: I was hoping the results after the `eps` expansion will be something of simpler form but it is already with Hypergeometric etc.

Comment: In your approach why didn't you try integrating the integrand in terms of `r` ? You checked the `Series` in `r` and then tried the original integrand in `t`. Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: @BabaYaga:  Thank you.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica v12.2 is able to evaluate the first form of the integral (with general exponent `a=-1/2+eps`):

```
Integrate[Log[1 - t] t^a/(1 + t), {t, 0, 1}]
```

and gives the restriction `Re[a]>-1`

```
int = Integrate[Log[1 - t] t^a/(1 + t), {t, 0, 1},Assumptions -> Re[a] > -1]
```

$\frac{\Gamma (a+2) \left(2
   \left(\text{Hypergeometric2F1Regularized}^{(0,0,1,0)}(1,a+1,a+3,-1)+\text{Hypergeometric2F1Regularized}^{(0,1
   ,0,0)}(1,a+1,a+3,-1)\right)-\text{HypergeometricPFQRegularized}^{(\{0,0,0\},\{0,1\},0)}\left(\{1,2,2\},\{a+3,
   2\},\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)-2 H_{a+1}}{4 (a+1)}$

The formula holds for `eps>-1/2`

```
Plot[int /. a -> -1/2 + eps, {eps, -1/2, 2},AxesLabel -> {eps, "int[eps]"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: In fact, yhe formula holds for `eps > -3/2` as shown in my answer, making use of 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: @user64494 Perhaps Mathematica v13 `Integrate[Log[1 - t] t^a/(1 + t), {t, 0, 1} ]` gives a stronger condition for a? v12 only gives `a>-1` ( `eps>-1/2`)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann    In 13.1.0 its the same `Re[a] > -1`.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`NSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NumericalCalculus/ref/NSeries.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

int[eps_] = 
 Assuming[eps > -1/2, 
  Integrate[(Log[1 - t] t^(-(1/2) + eps))/(1 + t), {t, 0, 1}] // Simplify]
```

[image]

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

intApprox[eps_] = 
 NSeries[int[eps], {eps, 0, 18}, WorkingPrecision -> 15] // Normal

(* -0.7431381432026 + 0.4269973678628 eps - 0.2812548075579 eps^2 + 
 0.1895607297093 eps^3 - 0.1279652435101 eps^4 + 0.0861500457739 eps^5 - 
 0.0578267139030 eps^6 + 0.0387251026194 eps^7 - 0.0258911737789 eps^8 + 
 0.0172919781863 eps^9 - 0.0115408785430 eps^10 + 0.0076991971011 eps^11 - 
 0.0051349443936 eps^12 + 0.0034241649584 eps^13 - 0.0022831270543 eps^14 + 
 0.0015222257158 eps^15 - 0.0010148737927 eps^16 + 0.0006766052580 eps^17 - 
 0.0004510792839 eps^18 *)

Plot[{int[eps], intApprox[eps]}, {eps, -3/2, 3/2},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.8, .5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I was not aware of `NSeries`. It confirms that the expansion method should work in this case. Also my original attempt in terms `r` and `Integrate` in the question is giving the wrong result. This is a little scary!

Comment: Another way is as follows. Execute  `Series[(Log[1 - t] t^(-(1/2) + eps))/(1 + t), {eps, 0, 5}] // Normal` and then `NIntegrate[Log[1 - t]/(Sqrt[t] (1 + t)), {t, 0, 1}] + 
 NIntegrate[(Log[1 - t] Log[t])/(Sqrt[t] (1 + t)), {t, 0, 1}]*eps + 
 NIntegrate[( Log[1 - t] Log[t]^2)/(2 Sqrt[t] (1 + t)), {t, 0, 1}]*
  eps^2 + NIntegrate[( Log[1 - t] Log[t]^3)/(
   6 Sqrt[t] (1 + t)), {t, 0, 1}]*eps^3 + 
 NIntegrate[(Log[1 - t] Log[t]^4)/(24 Sqrt[t] (1 + t)), {t, 0, 1}]*
  eps^4 + NIntegrate[( Log[1 - t] Log[t]^5)/(
   120 Sqrt[t] (1 + t)), {t, 0, 1}]*eps^5` which results in

Comment: `-0.743138 + 0.426997 eps - 0.281255 eps^2 + 0.189561 eps^3 - 
 0.127965 eps^4 + 0.08615 eps^5`

Comment: @user64494.    This is not different from what I did for NIntegrate in the question. If you see the EDIT2, the problem is with Integrate. Unfortunately I can not check this in newer version.